# How to add columns to a new dataframe using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe that will be exported to csv using selected columns from the existing dataframe.

I've tried using a for loop to add every column within range(14, var_x, 2). So all the even numbered columns after columns[14].

original code:

```
var_col_length=len(df.columns)

for x in range(14, var_col_length, 2):
    new_dataframe=df[df.columns[x]]
```

using append:

```
var_col_length=len(df.columns)

for x in range(14, var_col_length, 2):
    new_dataframe=new_dataframe.append(df[df.columns[x]])


TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I either get only the last column, since as expected of the above code it keeps rewriting the dataframe "new_dataframe", when I tried using .append I get an error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.iloc`

```py
new_df = df.iloc[:, 14:var_col_length:2]
```

Comment: How could I add an if or where statement to it?

Comment: @Mitch The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) on ``loc`` and ``iloc`` provides example to select rows and columns based on some conditions.

Comment: Ya I can't find an example using endswith() and I'm getting an error when I try.

Comment: @Mitch Scroll around for ``endswith`` and ``startswith`` on here, I'm sure you'll find something !

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df[df.columns[np.arange(14,var_col_length,2)]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ferran how would you an "if" statement to that?

Comment: `df.columns.isin()` for filtering columns with conditions